# Sharepoint list to Power Query Load

Tags: list, sharepoint, powerquery

I am using a Sharepoint onlne list as a Source for Power BI. There are 67 sharepoint online lists , whom i have to append together, and then map it to an excel in my Local Disk.

I have given the Table.Buffer command which i helps to load the table faster. But still it takes long time for the table to load.

Can anyone help me with this Issue or provide an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the way Excel loads the data you cannot really make it faster.  You can try disabling "Background Data" (go to Query Options > Data Load > deselect 'Allow data preview to download in the background') option but that is limited performance enhancement.  Here are some articles on the subject:

https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-forum/power-query/any-way-to-speed-up-really-slow-refresh-times-in-power-query

https://powerpivotpro.com/2017/07/power-query-refresh-speeds-suck/

But there is a better way!!! You can connect your PowerBI directly to the Sharepoint lists without the Excel step and it will be much faster!

[image: See Connection Options in Screenshot below]